# CSS Border Property Strange Bahavier when Positioned Absolute

Tags: html, css

I am creating shapes with `CSS3` so i have created a rod type shape with `CSS3` with following CSS;

```
.rod {
    border-radius: 39px;
    border: 17px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
```

I need it be on the top of other `div's` so i positioned it absolute, but `position: absolute;` makes it round shape, I am wondering what makes it turned to round shape what connection does `position: absolute` and `border` property has.

```
.rod {
    border-radius: 39px;
    border: 17px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle with Position Absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/zomw1jwa/)

I know the fix but i don't know the reason.

Comment: Adding position absolute removes the 'block' formatting so the element collapses to the size defined by the other properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element that is positioned absolute collapses around it's content, while a div is normally displayed as a 'block' that greedily takes up the entire width. You get the same behaviour when you would use `display:inline-block` instead of `position:absolute`.

The fix is to explicitely state the width of the element:

```
.rod {
    border-radius: 39px;
    border: 17px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify a `width` style to the `rod` element that's why it becomes a round object (*Absolute positioned elements are 0 width by default if it has no contents*). Try adding a width or text inside the div and you will now see that it becomes a longer rod :)

Sample:

```
.rod {
    border-radius: 39px;
    border: 17px solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    transform: rotate(-6deg);
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```